# Unable to check dll injection and debug-MS detours

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, monitoring, detours

I had written a file monitor using ms detours.i have to hook file related calls like creatfile,readfile in any targetexecutable  and collect stats from those calls.

I have an injector

```
    void CFileStat::MonitorProcess()
    {

    int npos=filename.ReverseFind('\\');
    CString name=filename.Mid(npos+1);
    WCHAR* DirPath = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR* FullPath = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, DirPath);
    DWORD processID = FindProcessId(name);

    if ( processID == 0 )
        AfxMessageBox(L"Could not find ");
        else
          AfxMessageBox(L"Process ID is ");
         swprintf_s(FullPath, MAX_PATH, L"%s\\%s", DirPath,strhookdll);

         LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege = L"SeDebugPrivilege";
// Change this BOOL value to set/unset the SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED attribute
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege = TRUE;
    HANDLE hToken;
// Open a handle to the access token for the calling process. That is this running program
 if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
 {
    printf("OpenProcessToken() error %u\n", GetLastError());
    return ;
 }

BOOL test = SetPrivilege(hToken, lpszPrivilege, bEnablePrivilege);


HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);

if( ! hProcess ) 
{ 
    return; 
}

LPVOID LoadLibraryAddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"),
        "LoadLibraryA");

LPVOID LLParam = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, lstrlen(FullPath),
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

if( ! LLParam )
{
    printf( "ERROR: Problems with VirtualAllocEx.  Error code: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}
int n=WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, LLParam, FullPath, lstrlen(FullPath), NULL);

    if(n == 0) {
    printf("Error: there was no bytes written to the process's address space.\n");
}

   HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)     LoadLibraryAddr,
        LLParam, NULL, NULL);

   if(threadID == NULL) {
    printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created.\n");
    }
   else 
   {
    printf("Success: the remote thread was successfully created.\n");
    }

   WaitForSingleObject(threadID, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    delete [] DirPath;
    delete [] FullPath;
```

I have the hook dll

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include "detours.h"
  #include"FileDetour.h"

  #pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")




  void AddHook(PVOID* func,PVOID intercept); 
  void DeleteHook(PVOID* func,PVOID intercept); 

  static HANDLE (WINAPI * PCreateFile)(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD      
  dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD 
  dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile) = CreateFile;

  HANDLE WINAPI InterceptCreateFile(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD    
  dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, 
 DWORD     dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile);

  BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpReserved )
   {
  FILE *file;
     fopen_s(&file, "D:\\temp.txt", "a+");
  DWORD Error=0;
      // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
      switch( fdwReason ) 
    {  
         case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
     // Initialize once for each new process.
     // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
        fprintf(file, "DLL attach function called.\n");
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
                    OutputDebugString(L"Attaching filedetour.dll");

     // DetourRestoreAfterWith();
           DetourTransactionBegin();
           DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)PCreateFile, InterceptCreateFile);
           Error=DetourTransactionCommit();



        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                 break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
     // Do thread-specific cleanup.
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        fprintf(file, "DLL dettach function called.\n");
                    OutputDebugString(L"De-Attaching MyDLL.dll");
             DWORD Error=0;

           DetourTransactionBegin();
           DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
           DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)PCreateFile,InterceptCreateFile);
           Error=DetourTransactionCommit();

            break;  
         }

          fclose(file);
      return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

       }


        HANDLE WINAPI InterceptCreateFile(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD 
        dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD 
         dwCreationDisposition,     DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile)

     {
     OutputDebugString(lpFileName);
    return PCreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, 
        dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
       }
```

CreateRemotethread returns successfully and I am going to waitforsingleobject in the injector function.

but I am getting no evidence of dll being injected into the target exe process space.i tried ollydbg.the debug is not hitting the hook dll project named "filedetour" when i debug the target exe as well the injector process .Neither the text file temp.txt is being created.when i debug the target exe for one or two lines , I get a debug window message the thread is exiting.The waitforsingleobejct in the injector process immediately signals.

in short there is no evidence a dll was injected sucessfuly and that dllmain was hit at all.

how to debug the entire process?iwant to debug the hook dll throroughly from the target exe as the hook dll collects stats from the file operations.

what are the files I have to copy from the hook dll project(dll,lib,.h) and any extra settings to be made to the injector project?

I am new to this topic.

Comment: I would strive to use a higher level of abstraction. As it is, even though I have some experience with detours I don't feel like taking on this code to help you. For example, use string objects instead of allocating raw arrays with `new`. Do you ever deallocate those strings?

Comment: If the remote thread is created but the DLL not loaded, then you may have a dependency problem with the DLL when LoadLibraryA tries to load it. If detours.lib is an import lib, then maybe the detours DLL must be put somewhere where it will be found by the loader, in the context of the injected process.

Comment: I remember doing something similar with CDetours, I did hook and logged all dll's being "injected" (loaded) into my process, thing is a lot of antiviruses or third part processes do inject a dll into your process, so if you're looking to block something checking what is injected via `LoadLibraryA/LoadLibraryW` this isn't of much help. You can always do it with CDetours, I remember it worked fine.

Comment: @alf,yes those strings are deallocatd at the end...@manuel,you have given me an important info..that may most likely to be the problem...but I tested with an explicit loadlibrary call which works with the same path.

Comment: I found that ASLR could cause problems with the mismatching address of LoadLibrary in source and injected process...how to avoid this?...I cannot see any other explanation since an explicit loadlibrary in the injected process is working

Comment: @user1914725 By "same path", do you mean the path of the DLL or the path of the injected EXE?

Comment: @manuel,full path of the hook dll...Loadlibrary(fullpath of hook dll) works in target exe(i.e to be injected) ...this call is ONLY for verification as you said loadlibrary could be a problem...however when I try inject the hook dll, the remote thread in target exe exits immediately..

Comment: @user1914725 Did you try to inject another super simple DLL of your own? (that is, is the problem specific to the "detours" DLL?)

Comment: I tried the detourcreateprocesswithdll route as well...its giving the "the application failed to initialize oxc00007cb" eoor when its called...is it a problem with privileges?..shud I run all this code only from an admin account?

Comment: i have only one detours dll which is right now failrly simple with the most basic dll and hooking  code...as this is the first time i even touched the api...however i have tried two injectors with creatremotethread and detourcreateprocess

Comment: will a filesystem driver fetch more read/write stats like (RPS,WPS) than hooking readfile/writefile? if that's the case, i can start try that route atleast...i haven't written a driver before though...not sure if its worth effort and time

Comment: I got the createprocess approach done...however I am still puzzled why on earth is createremotethread approach failing?  Loadlibrary address seems the most likely issue..does ASLR come in here?